# EclipseLink JPA + Liquibase integration

Tags: liquibase

I have a currently working JPA project.The persistence.xml looks like this

```
<persistence-unit name="per1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<class>TResource</class>
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
<properties><property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In the current condition,the schema is generated by TResource.
Now I want to remove the TResource and create the schema by liquibase.
I want the entityManagerFactory to not create table instead run liquibase to create the schema and bind the schema with entityManagerFactory. Any help?

Comment: A good article on how JPA and liquibase can co-exist: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/cloud-platform/blog/2012/12/04/making-liquibase-rock-solid

Comment: Did the above comment answer your question?  If so, would you please close the question?